# jQuery Mobile and jQuery.mobile.back();

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a Back button:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-role="button" data-inline="true" 
   data shadow='true' data-corners='true' id='goBackfromExerc'
   onClick="goBackfromExerc()">Yes</a>
   <!---the function goBackfromExerc() ends with jQuery.mobile.back(); -->
```

that uses this simple line of code to go back to the previous page:

```
jQuery.mobile.back();
```

But that button is inside a popup that causes this to appear on the Chrome URL: `#&ui-state=dialog`. I think that causes the issue since `window.location.hash` sees it as a URL all by itself.

It works on Google Chrome. It works on my friend's Android phone, but it does not work on my Android phone.

I have heard about this problem happening to other users, but mine only affects my Android phone.

Comment: What event are you using, perhaps click? Can you post the button handler?

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem in the popup itself:

I needed data-hisstory="false" or the popup itself would behave like a page. The Back button was simply closing the popup.